# Adding cookies to toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

So im trying to add cookies to the "toggle" part of my website, problem is, I tried other methods, and they do work, but either the icon gets out of sync or the scriptd within the toggled div gets messed up. So how can I work around with these problems? Thanks a bunch!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#top4trigger").click(function () {
        $("#top4hide").slideToggle("slow")
        $("i", this).toggleClass("fa fa-chevron-up fa fa-chevron-down")
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need jQuery cookie for this to work.

```
$.cookie('your_cookie_name', 'your_cookie_value', { path: '/' });
```

You can try something like:

```
if ($(this).hasClass("class-name")) {
    // add and remove classes and cookie
  } else {
    // add and remove classes and cookie
}
```

Comment: Ayee, I tried adding jquery cookie, but it would mess up the jquery script within that div and put my button out of sync.